# Two DKIM signatures in outgoing messages

Tags: postfix, gmail, dkim

I have `DKIM` and `SPF` correctly configured on my server with postfix `myserver.com`.   However, when I send emails from Gmail configured to authenticate and send email as `myname@myserver.com` authenticating against postfix on `myserver.com`, the email ends up having two `DKIM` signatures.  I can only assume that Gmail is adding a `DKIM` signature.  Is there any easy way to resolve this so that I only have one `DKIM` signature?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question.  The problem resolved itself.  It appears to be a case of a previous DKIM DNS signature continuing to propagate.  24 hours later, the problem has disappeared.